Network Interface name change while updating 22.04
Last week I was updating a physical server, and after a reboot the names on some of my network interfaces changed.
There was sometime in the past the change to predictable nic names, but I am curious to why this happened while my update was staying inside the 22.04 tree.
Even more, as it seems the needed config file had to be altered even more to get the interfaces up and running again: (netplan config)
    ens2f0np0:
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
    ens2f1np1:
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false

As it seems the dhcp4 and dhcp6 tags were not needed beforehand.
Is anyone able to point me to the exact scene where I could have been warned that this is going to happen with this update?
I update once a month with upgrade and dist-upgrade.
Unfortunately I have no record left of the nic names before my alter.

See these references: https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/119gkfu/name_of_my_ethernet_adapter_changed_after/ ,,,,https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkInterfaceNames#How_to_get_it_back,,,, https://serverfault.com/questions/741210/disabling-predictable-network-interface-names-in-xubuntu-15-10
